# How to insert a null value to GUID column in Table using C#?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I searched the entire web. I wonder why this easy task is so hard to accomplish in C#.

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@someid", System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value =
string.IsNullOrEmpty(class.someid) ? System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid.Null : new Guid(class.someid);
```

This returns an error :

> Failed to convert parameter value from string to guid

My stored procedure updates a record in the table with the parameters relayed by C#.

What I want to do is to update a record and its specific column with null value by using a stored procedure which passes a `guid` parameter from C# with `guid` that can sometimes be null in value. Is this possible in C#?

Comment: Try to use `DBNull.Value` instead of `System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid.Null`.

Comment: @Wulworine it says No implicit conversion between System.DBNull and System.Guid,

I tried (object)DBNull.Value, it built successfully but it gave me the same error.

Comment: DBNull.Value will work for string and guids.

Comment: Can you post your full code of block in your question?

Comment: See my new updated topic post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try:

```
sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@someid", System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value =
string.IsNullOrEmpty(class.someid) ? System.Guid.Empty : new Guid(class.someid);
```

If the casting doesn't work. And in your table make sure if this column allows null.
And `class.someid` has the correct format for the constructor.
You can check on this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ff78dc.aspx) to have an overview.

Comment: it gives me the same error. Failed to convert parameter value from a Guid to a String.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure to provide the correct format to the constructor of the `Guid` structure?

Comment: I did it the hard way. this post gave me the idea.

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(page.UserId))
                 {
                     userparam = new SqlParameter("@UserId", System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid.Null);
                     sqlcmd.Parameters.Add(userparam);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@UserId", System.Data.SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = new Guid(page.UserId);
                 }

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, your column `ID` is of `Guid` type in your database, but your parameter is string.

You can convert your parameter to `SqlGuid`

```
command.Parameters.Add("@GuidParameter", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier).Value = new System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlGuid(YourGuid); //The value of @ID
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlguid.aspx

Also try the following in the stored procedure:

```
Declare @someid uniqueidentifier = null
```

Declaring nullable property:

```
public Guid? column1;
```

Assigning Null:

```
column1 = null;
```